# Is there any way to query a list of users who can access a VPN connection in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: vpn, powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I was wondering if it is possible to query (powershell, ADUC, etc) and generate a list of users who are able to login to a VPN server running on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Is the main thing that controls the ability to connect to VPN for a given user just depend on the settings on the Dial In tab?

Edit

For Techie007, here is the error output

```
 Select-Object : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is
null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value.
At C:\Users\itsupport\function.ps1:5 char:58
+     $dialin = Get-ADUser $username -Properties * | select <<<<  -ExpandProper
ty msNPAllowDialin
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], PSArgument
   NullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Selec
   tObjectCommand
```

The above output gets printed out over and over and over, and then it will print a single username, and then show the error again, and then print another username, and then show the error again.   Any idea as to why it is doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the main thing that controls the ability to connect to VPN for a given user just depend on the settings on the Dial In tab?

Yes, and you can get it with PowerShell (run on a domain controller) like this:

```
$usernames = Get-ADUser -Filter * | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

foreach ($username in $usernames) {

    $dialin = Get-ADUser $username -Properties * | select -ExpandProperty msNPAllowDialin

    if ($dialin -eq "True") {
        Write-Output $username
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can get it from a command-prompt (run on a domain controller) using `dsquery`:

```
dsquery * -Filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(msNPAllowDialin=TRUE))"
```

Comment: adding error output to original question.   the first one worked, somewhat, but with some error output between each username..

Comment: hmm, which version of PowerShell are you using (`$psversiontable.PSVersion` run in PowerShell will tell you)?

Comment: Looks like PowerShell v2 :(   I was able to filter out the errors and get the data I needed from your first PowerShell script.

Comment: BTW Techie007, you have saved my ass so many times.   I just wanted to be sure you were aware how much I appreciate your help.   Thank you!

Comment: No problem Richie, I appreciate it. ;)  PS: 2008R2 support up to PowerShell Version 5 (latest right now).   You should AT LEAST upgrade it to PS3, as 3 is significantly better than 2. If you're not running an older Exchange or SBS version, you could even go to v5 (but double check/google compatibility with services you have running before doing that).

Comment: I'd love to upgrade, but I'm on a project that will only be ongoing for another day and this is a production environment that I am not responsible for.  If they want to upgrade they can, but I always try to be hands off when it comes to someone else's production environment.